# C++ Pointer not being updated?

Tags: c++

Not exactly sure how to word the title but I'll explain as best I can.
I have a program that originally used a 2D array of a set size and so it was defined as:

```
typedef char Map[Row][Col];
```

I'm now trying to dynamically allocate memory for it and it has now also become of variable size based on input. It's now defined as:

```
typedef char** Map;
```

In my main method, I originally had:

```
Map map;
readUserInput(map);
```

Basically readUserInput takes the map array as a parameter, and assigns values to it based on user input. The map then contains values and is used in other functions.

I've updated the readUserInput function so that it dynamically sizes the array and it allocates/deallocates memory for it. This works fine, but the problem comes from the fact that now in the main method, map is not being updated. The above code in main now looks like:

```
Map map = nullptr;
readUserInput(map);
```

but after running the readUserInput function, map is still null. Inside of the function, map is updated fine, so I'm not understanding the difference made between the changes.

Comment: Do you allocate the array in `readUserInput`? Where is the `new` call?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: `readUserInput(map);` must take input by `reference`

Answer (score 2):

What you pass to function is  a pointer to array and fuction can't change it. But replacing array with pointer to pointer is incorrect in most case.Pointer to pointer suggest that have a 1D array of pointers. Which may (or may not) point to other arrays. Such data organization sometimes referred to as *jagged arrays*, because it allows each row to be of separate length. But on practtice jagged arrays and their subclass, sparse matrices, usually implemented as 1D array to avoid re-allocation.

To avoid decaying and to actually store a monolithic array in memory, you should use 1d array and, preferably,  encapsulation for pointer arithmetic and reallocation, and then pass reference to object that stores all required states. Reference ensures that object is mutable by function ( a smart-pointer-less version for an example):

```
class Map 
{
    int rows, cols;
    char *data;
public:
    Map() : rows(), cols(), data(nullptr) {}
    Map(int r, int c) : rows(r), cols(c), data(new char[r*c]()) {}
    ~Map() { delete[] data; }

    void resize(int r, int c) {
        if(rows == r && cols == c) return;

        char* tmp = new char[r*c]();

        if(data) 
        {
            // copy old data here if required


            delete[] data;
        }
        row = r; col = c;
        data = tmp;
    }

    char& operator() (int r, int c) { return data[r*cols + c]; }
    char operator() (int r, int c) const  { return data[r*cols + c]; }
};
```

*NB: this class requires a copy and move operations to be implemented if any copy must be allowed.*

The function prototype would be:

```
void readUserInput(Map& map);
```

With such class you can do dynamic resizing, store its size, and address element as simple as this:

```
int main()
{
    Map test(4, 5); // declaring and allocating memory

    test.resize(3,3);   // reallocating

    test(1,1) = 3; // writing

    //reading
    std::cout << +test(1,1) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function should accept the array by reference in the  C terms like

```
readUserInput( &map );
```

when the function is declared like

```
void readUserInput( Map *map );
```

or in the C++ terms when the function is declared like for example

```
void readUserInput( Map &map );
```

and called like

```
readUserInput(map);
```

Instead of allocating dynamically arrays you could use the container `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: .. and here comes three star code (even if one star is hidden as reference). It must be said that we don't really need pointer to pointer to address storage of two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have used is a pure C-style code, and is prone to many mistakes:

1. You use `typedef` instead of: `using Map = char**;`
2. You use a function which gets a pointer and fills it, which is more common in C than in C++.

   3. You use raw pointer instead of smart pointers (added in C++11), which may cause a memory leak in the end.

> I've updated the readUserInput function so that it dynamically sizes the array and it allocates/deallocates memory for it.

This means that now it should be a ***class*** named Map, since it should be able to allocate/deallocate, insert and remove values, and is a valid container. Actually, you are creating a type of `std::vector` here, and if you don't create it for you own learning process, I strongly suggest you to use the `std` containers!

It is possible to pass both pointer and references in C++, notice that:

- You can pass a reference only if the value isn't ***nullptr***.
- When there should be a value, reference is recommended.

In this case, your function should look like

```
void readUserInput(Map* map);
```

and should be called using:

```
readUserInput(&map);
```